# Limit the difference between the sinuses.

Tags: limits

What is wrong?

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\sin(\sqrt[3]{n^3-9})-\sin(n)) =
$$
$$
= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}2\sin(\frac{\sqrt[3]{n^3-9}-n}{2})\cos(\frac{\sqrt[3]{n^3-9}+n}{2}) =
$$
$$
= 2\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin(\frac{n(\sqrt[3]{1-\frac{9}{n^3}}-1)}{2})\cos(\frac{n(\sqrt[3]{1-\frac{9}{n^3}}+1)}{2}) =
$$
$$
= 2\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin(\frac{n*0}{2})\cos(\frac{n*2}{2}) =
$$

$$
= 2\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin(0)\cos(n) = 0;
$$

But [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20%28sin%28%28n%5E3-9%29%5E%281%2F3%29%29-sin%28n%29%29) get another answer.

Comment: The limit which you transform into $n * 0$ is actually an indeterminate limit of the form infinity times zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is zero but you do have a mistake in your working.

The expression $n\left(\sqrt[3]{1-\frac{9}{n^3}}-1\right)$ is indeterminate as it is of the form $\infty\times0$. You can evaluate that term using L'hopital:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\sqrt[3]{1-\frac{9}{n^3}}-1\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(1-9n^{-3}\right)^\frac{1}{3}-1}{n^{-1}}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{9n^{-4}\left(1-9n^{-3}\right)^{-\frac{2}{3}}}{-n^{-2}}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}-9n^{-2}\left(1-9n^{-3}\right)^{-\frac{2}{3}}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}-9\left(n^3-9\right)^{-\frac{2}{3}}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}-\frac{9}{\left(n^3-9\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$
$$=0$$
And from this point your working would follow.

WolframAlpha's answer is vague: "-2 to 2" which suggests that maybe it didn't succeed at its calculation (it has built in limit for the time of calculation). I also tried the same expression in Wolfram Mathematica and got zero like you did so you are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use $$\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{n^3-9}-n}2=\dfrac{n^3-9-n^3}{(n^3-9)^{2/3}+(n^3-9)^{1/3}n+n^2}$$

$$\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{n^3-9}-n}2=0$$

$$\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{n^3-9}-n}2=\sin0=0$$

Answer (score 0):

The sine function is uniformly continuous (because, for example, it has a bounded derivative.) Therefore, since the difference between the two arguments tends to infinity as n tends to infinity, the difference between their sines also tends to zero.