# Limit with -inf result, but how?

Tags: limits

What do with this:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(n-\sqrt[3]{n^3+2})}
$$

[Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%201%2F%28n%5E0.5%28n-%28n%5E3%2B2%29%5E%281%2F3%29%29%29) say -inf, but how?

Comment: Try this method : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565600/limit-the-difference-between-the-sinuses/1565644#1565644

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fact that $(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2) = a^3-b^3$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(n-\sqrt[3]{n^3+2})}
={} &
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\color{red}{n^2 + n\sqrt[3]{n^3+2} + \sqrt[3]{(n^3+2)^2}}}{\sqrt{n}\left(n-\sqrt[3]{n^3+2}\right)\color{red}{\left(n^2 + n\sqrt[3]{n^3+2} + \sqrt[3]{(n^3+2)^2}\right)}}
\\
={} &
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^2 + n\sqrt[3]{n^3+2} + \sqrt[3]{(n^3+2)^2}}{\sqrt{n}\left(n^3-(n^3+2)\right)}
\\
={} &
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^2\left(1 + \sqrt[3]{1+\frac{2}{n^3}} + \sqrt[3]{\left(1+\frac{2}{n^3}\right)^2}\right)}{-2\sqrt{n}}
\\
={} &
-\infty
\end{align}

Comment: Great! Thanks! It's right for me!

Answer (score 0):

$$
-f(n)=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}(n-\sqrt[3]{n^3+2})} = n^{-\frac32}\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac2{n^3}}-1\right)^{-1} \\
$$
but
$$
\sqrt[3]{1+\frac2{n^3}}-1 \lt \frac1{n^3}
$$
correspondingly
$$
-f(n) \gt n^{\frac32}
$$